# html tag within php code: <<<HTML

Tags: php, html

I was reading Google Analytics API documentation and noticed a syntax I've never seen/used before:

```
<script>
<?php
<<<HTML
  cxApi.setChosenVariation(
    $chosenVariation,             // The index of the variation shown to the visitor
    $experimentId                 // The id of the experiment the user has been exposed to
  );
HTML;
?>
</script>
```

What does `<<<HTML` do, what's this called?

Comment: Called as [Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Comment: [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is PHP's [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). Basically it works like this:

```
<div>
<?php
echo <<<EOL
Write stuff here,
no need to worry about double " quotes or single ' quotes
Just write on.
When done end it like this:
EOL;
?>
</div>
```

Comment: THanks! So what's the difference between `EOL` and `HTML`? I'm off to read the documentation (probably answer my own question too)

Comment: No difference, it's your word of choosing. Of course, it has some limitations and rules, for example the ending EOL; has to end with a semicolon and be the only thing in the line, nothing before or after. Read the documentation to understand better. It's not that useful, but I guess it's good for big texts when you don't wanna escape all sorts of quotation marks.

Answer (score 4):

It's called HEREDOC string. From docs:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 3):

Its called the heredoc syntax. You can check it out on the PHP site [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Comment: Oi everyone on this site is too fast at posting ;)